# Rails Hstore dateTime saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, hstore

How do i use datetime values and store and retrieve them using HStore?

I am using this:

```
module HstoreAccessor
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hstore_accessor(hstore_attribute, *keys)
      Array(keys).flatten.each do |key|
        define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
          send("#{hstore_attribute}=", (send(hstore_attribute) || {}).merge(key.to_s => value))
          send("#{hstore_attribute}_will_change!")
        end
        define_method(key) do
          send(hstore_attribute) && send(hstore_attribute)[key.to_s]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, HstoreAccessor)
```

to define the accessors and it works great for everything except dates. I get some wierd stuff in my test cases when i compare the date from the saved and retrieved model with the date from the model that is not yet saved. Basically the date before the save is a "Time" class and afterwards its a String.

I realize that hstore keeps things as strings but i have difficulties figuring out how it serializes the date so i can reverse it the same way in the getter/setters for the field.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it serializes it using 'to_s', so to deserialize it back to Time instance `Time#parse` should be enough

Comment: I tried that but it was also giving me issues. The way i went was that i saved all the timestamps as iso8601 strings and added a validator just to pass that format. My app mostly acts as a json API because i use client side javascript for the UI so it will do just fine. I will probably need to do adjustments when i will be making the date-specific queries in my database